# How do I answer this question correctly using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

"The second report presents a complete list of students with the subjects each has undertaken, their result for that subject, and their average mark for the units taken.

The columns required are as follows:

```
student ID,
forename,
surname,
subject ID,
result
```

After each student display, the report should also display the average mark obtained by each student for their program.

An overall average mark should be displayed at the end of the report."

I am very new to SQL so any help on the syntax for this question would be greatly appreciated.

At the moment I have gotten as far as displaying all the columns with all the student details using:

```
select student.student_ID
     , student.forename
     , student.surname
     , result.subject_ID
     , result.result 
  from student
     , result;
```

But it gives me all the results as the same for whatever reason

[image]

As I said i'm not very handy with sql so even just a pseudo-syntaz would be great explaining what I have to do to get this done would be great.

It should be simple for someone with basic sql knowledge i'd imagine.

Thanks in advance

Connor

UPDATE: [progress pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjcGK.png)

However when adding group by. i seem to get the results for only one class? Do I need to group by something else?
[One class pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyeVf.png)

Thanks guys i've been on discord severs looking for help for hours and this is defo helping me a lot more. cheers

UPDATE2:

[I now get this by adding ROLLUP, its looking good but I don't think these averages correspond to each individual student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMqGr.png)

Sorry for being so bad at this... 
 I'm dumb the 4th row down for each student is the average..it is correct...but is it supposed to display like this?

Comment: At this point, 20 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be beneficial

Comment: "But it gives me all the results".  What do you expect???  You just do a straight `JOIN` without any filtering.

Comment: Also, learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any relationship between the rows of `student` and `result` in your query. So it simply returns every combination of rows in the tables -- this is called a cross product or cross join.

You need to indicate how the rows should be paired up so each student is only shown with their own results, not those of other students. You do this with a `JOIN` with `ON` condition.

```
SELECT student.student_ID, student.forename, student.surname, result.subject_ID, result.result 
FROM student
JOIN result ON student.student_ID = result.student_ID
```

To get the average for each student, you need to use `GROUP BY student.student_ID` along with the aggregation function `AVG()`.

```
SELECT student.student_ID, student.forename, student.surname, AVG(result.result) AS avg_result
FROM student
JOIN result ON student.student_ID = result.student_ID
GROUP BY student.student_ID
```

To get an overall average, you leave out the grouping. In this case you don't even need to join with the `student` table.

```
SELECT AVG(result) AS avg_result
FROM result
```

You can get all the results in a single query by using the `WITH ROLLUP` option.

```
SELECT student.student_ID, student.forename, student.surname, AVG(result.result) AS avg_result
FROM student
JOIN result ON student.student_ID = result.student_ID
GROUP BY student.student_ID, result.subject_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

The average per student will have `subject_ID = NULL`, the overall average will have `student_ID = NULL`.

Comment: Thank you..I seem to be making progress now..I have a full list of each student, subject and grade as desired, however when i then add the group by I get only get one row as a result. Also in the question i think it is asking for result and average result of each individual in the same table. - really appreciate the help btw

Comment: Use `WITH ROLLUP` to get all the subtotals in a single query.

Answer (score -1):

In the query you don't specify the value that links both tables.

Does the result table have a key column to contain the student_ID?

Then the query should at least state that these should be equal

Use your query as is and add a where clause.

```sql
select 
  student.student_ID, 
  student.forename, 
  student.surname, 
  result.subject_ID, 
  result.result 
from student, result 
where student.student_ID = result.student_ID
```

Comment: Really???  `student.student_ID = result.subject_ID`?  You are linking `John` to `Math`?

Comment: On my phone browser I didn't see the result table in the question. So nope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! made some progress, ill update to where i am so you guys can have a look!